# convert jquery ajax method to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

purpose:When we clicking on a link it opens a new window going to gotopage2.aspx.Please help in understanding the code. what does the data parameter in function() contain? the ajax request settings say that request is synchronous and if success run the function. How is the url parameter being used in this context? How can i write the below function in pure javascript without using jquery/ajax settings?

```
$.ajax({
      url:      "page1.aspx?Q=userSess1",
      async:    false,
      success:  function(data) {
        if(data.substring(0, 1)=="1") {        
            if(mywindow){
                mywindow.focus();                  
            }
            else{
                mywindow=open('gotopage2.aspx','newwindow home page');
            }
        }
        else {
            alert("fail");
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is to open a particular URL in a new window, you don't need any fancy JS. All you need is a hyperlink, with the target attribute set to _blank, like so:

```
<a href="gotopage2.aspx" target="_blank">CLick me!</a>
```

AJAX is used to fetch information from the server and dynamically updating our page without refreshing the entire page and without opening a new window. For example, retrieving some JSON from a WEB API endpoint URL.

The url parameter in your ajax call is used to tell the browser where is should retrieve the data from. This is similar to typing "google.com" in your browser and pressing Enter. "Google.com" becomes the address from where the data is downloaded and displayed in your browser.

There are various alternatives to using $.ajax(). Most browsers nowadays have a function called fetch(), which essentially does the same as $.ajax(). Also, most browsers should support the XMLHttpRequest object which does the same. There are also third party JS libraries that can do AJAX as well, like axios and superagent. But as mentioned, if all you want is to open a new Window with a particular page, an  tag should suffice. Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you tutiplain. the reason for url in our request is to make sure we get some response so that if its success only then call a function. There are similar such functions every where in our code where sometimes the url value is some dll. Basically it sends a synchronous request to url:"library.dll" and if its success then it calls the redirect method. in addition to opening new window it also checks for the response..

Comment: That doesn't seem like a good idea to me. Not only are you overcomplicating your code, but if you are downloading .dll files to the client, you might be exposing your servers to security vulnerabilities. There are a number of different approaches you can take to conditionally execute code.